# Different uv or normal value for the same vertex in indexed geometry

Tags: three.js

Look at the following **indexed geometry**:

[image]

there are 2 faces and only 4 vertices so the buffers in three.js look like this (in pseudocode but the idea is clear):

```
position = [A, B, C, D]
index = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3] //[A, B, C, C, B, D]
```

vertices B and C are shared by two faces but **they are not repetead in position buffer**.

Is there any way to set vertex uv (or normal) based on the face it belongs to? I mean something like this:

```
position = [A, B, C, D]
index = [0,   1,   2,   2,   1,   3]
uv    = [uv1, uv2, uv3, uv4, uv5, uv6]
normal= [n1,  n2,  n3,  n4,  n5,  n6]
```

so the vertex C for example have different uv (uv3, uv4) and normal (n3, n4) values depending on the face.

Comment: I found a related question on Three.js forum, see [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/normals-wrong-when-indexed-geometry-shares-vertices/33282)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The idea behind indexed geometry is so that the same vertex can be reused across faces. What you’re describing is two different vertices that happen to have equal positions. But you can’t selectively choose which attributes are indexed and which ones are unique. The only way to get different UV values per vertex is to make the geometry non-indexed.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.toNonIndexed

Comment: Thanks! I get it but I'm curious... Could it be an easy-implementation feature by three.js guys or there is some kind of limitation in the way WebGL works?

Comment: It's two rendering alternatives provided by the WebGL API. [Non-indexed geometries use gl.drawArrays()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/drawArrays), while indexed geometries use [gl.drawElements()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/drawElements). There's nothing the Three.js team can do to create a hybrid method combining the two.